# grunt cssmin error: unable to create directory

Tags: gruntjs

I have configured the gruntfile as follows. When i execute "grunt" command at command prompt, jshint, clean and concat task works fine but when it comes to execute cssmin task, it gives out the following error.

[image]

One more thing to mention is when i restart my system, no error received and flow of work foes smoothly and generates desired results.
Could any one point reason for this problem.

Here is my gruntfile.js

```
    'use strict';

    module.exports = function (grunt) {

 // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
 require('time-grunt')(grunt);

// Automatically load required Grunt tasks
require('jit-grunt')(grunt, {useminPrepare: 'grunt-usemin'});

// Define the configuration for all the tasks
grunt.initConfig({
 pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

// Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
jshint: {
  options: {
    jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
    reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
  },

  all: {
    src: [
      //The JSHint task is set to examine all the JavaScript files in the app/scripts folder, and the Gruntfile.js and generate any reports of JS errors or warnings.
      'Gruntfile.js',
      'app/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
    ]
  }
},

copy: {
  dist: {
    cwd: 'app',
    src: [ '**','!styles/**/*.css','!scripts/**/*.js' ],
    dest: 'dist',
    expand: true
  },

  fonts: {
    files: [
      {
        //for bootstrap fonts
        expand: true,
        dot: true,
        cwd: 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist',
        src: ['fonts/*.*'],
        dest: 'dist'
      },
      {
        //for font-awesome
        expand: true,
        dot: true,
        cwd: 'bower_components/font-awesome',
        src: ['fonts/*.*'],
        dest: 'dist'
      }
    ]
  }
},

clean: {
  build: {
    src: [ 'dist/']
  }
},

useminPrepare: {
  html: 'app/menu.html',
  options: {
    dest: 'dist'
  }
},

// Concat
concat: {
  options: {
    separator: ';'
  },

  // dist configuration is provided by useminPrepare
  dist: {}
},

// Uglify
uglify: {
  // dist configuration is provided by useminPrepare
  dist: {}
},

cssmin: {
  dist: {}
},

// Filerev
filerev: {
  options: {
    encoding: 'utf8',
    algorithm: 'md5',
    length: 20
  },
  release: {
    // filerev:release hashes(md5) all assets (images, js and css in dist directory
    files: [{
      src: [
        'dist/scripts/*.js',
        'dist/styles/*.css',
      ]
    }]
  }
},

// Usemin
// Replaces all assets with their revved version in html and css files.
// options.assetDirs contains the directories for finding the assets
// according to their relative paths
usemin: {
  html: ['dist/*.html'],
  css: ['dist/styles/*.css'],
  options: {
    assetsDirs: ['dist', 'dist/styles']
  }
},

watch: {
  copy: {
    files: [ 'app/**', '!app/**/*.css', '!app/**/*.js'],
    tasks: [ 'build' ]
  },

  scripts: {
    files: ['app/scripts/app.js'],
    tasks:[ 'build']
  },

  styles: {
    files: ['app/styles/mystyles.css'],
    tasks:['build']
  },

  livereload: {
    options: {
      livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
    },

    files: [
      'app/{,*/}*.html',
      '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
      'app/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
    ]
  }
},

connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: 'localhost',
    livereload: 35729
  },

  dist: {
    options: {
      open: true,
      base:{
        path: 'dist',
        options: {
          index: 'menu.html',
          maxAge: 300000
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
   });

   grunt.registerTask('build', ['clean', 'jshint', 'useminPrepare', 
  'concat', 'cssmin', 'uglify', 'copy', 'filerev', 'usemin']);
   grunt.registerTask('default', ['build']);
   grunt.registerTask('serve',['build','connect:dist','watch']);
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe code below will help you:

```
//grunt.registerTask('build', ['styles', 'static']);
  grunt.registerTask('build', function() {
    grunt.file.mkdir('build/js');
    grunt.file.mkdir('build/fonts');
    grunt.file.mkdir('build/css');
    grunt.task.run(['stylus', 'copy', 'browserify']);
  });
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['build', 'watch']);
```

There is no `dist` folder, create one before run the build task.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was that I needed to add a trailing slash to my destination path in my copy task, i.e. from `dist` to `dist/`; it was outputting to file `dist` instead of folder `dist`.  Then when cssmin tried to create `dist/css` it couldn't because dist was not a folder.

Bad:

```
        copy: {
        html: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: './',
                src: ['*.html'],
                dest: 'dist'
            }],
```

Corrected:

```
        copy: {
        html: {
            files: [{
                exxpand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: './',
                src: ['*.html'],
                dest: 'dist/'
            }],
```